# Identify Consecutive Chunks in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have this table:

```
ValueId bigint // (identity) item ID
ListId bigint // group ID
ValueDelta int // item value
ValueCreated datetime2 // item created
```

What I need is to find consecutive Values within the same Group ordered by Created, not ID. Created and ID are not guaranteed to be in the same order.

So the output should be:

```
ListID bigint
FirstId bigint // from this ID (first in LID with Value ordered by Date)
LastId bigint // to this ID (last in LID with Value ordered by Date)
ValueDelta int // all share this value
ValueCount // and this many occurrences (number of items between FirstId and LastId)
```

I can do this with Cursors but I'm sure that's not the best idea so I'm wondering if this can be done in a query.

Please, for the answer *(if any)*, explain it a bit.

**UPDATE**: [**SQLfiddle basic data set**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5fb983/4/0)

Comment: You have more than enough rep to know that you need to provide actual details of your tables.

Comment: Sounds like you're dealing with the [gaps and islands problem](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Comment: No this isn't Gaps and Islands, this is TOP 1 Per Group.   Unless I'm mis-reading the question.

Comment: Added a sample SQLfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like a gaps-and-island problem.

Here is one way to do it. It would likely work faster than your variant.

The standard idea for gaps-and-islands is to generate two sets of row numbers partitioning them in two ways. The difference between such row numbers (`rn1-rn2`) would remain the same within each consecutive chunk. Run the query below CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to see what is going on.

```
WITH
CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT
        [ValueId]
        ,[ListId]
        ,[ValueDelta]
        ,[ValueCreated]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ListID ORDER BY ValueCreated) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ListID, [ValueDelta] ORDER BY ValueCreated) AS rn2
    FROM [Value]
)
SELECT
    ListID
    ,MIN(ValueID) AS FirstID
    ,MAX(ValueID) AS LastID
    ,MIN(ValueCreated) AS FirstCreated
    ,MAX(ValueCreated) AS LastCreated
    ,ValueDelta
    ,COUNT(*) AS ValueCount
FROM CTE_RN
GROUP BY
    ListID
    ,ValueDelta
    ,rn1-rn2
ORDER BY
    FirstCreated
;
```

This query produces the same result as yours on your sample data set.

It is not quite clear whether `FirstID` and `LastID` can be `MIN` and `MAX`, or they indeed must be from the first and last rows (when ordered by ValueCreated). If you need really first and last, the query would become a bit more complicated.

---

In your original sample data set the "first" and "min" for the `FirstID` are the same. Let's change the sample data set a little to highlight this difference:

```
insert into [Value]
([ListId], [ValueDelta], [ValueCreated])
values
(1, 1, '2019-01-01 01:01:02'), -- 1.1
(1, 0, '2019-01-01 01:02:01'), -- 2.1
(1, 0, '2019-01-01 01:03:01'), -- 2.2
(1, 0, '2019-01-01 01:04:01'), -- 2.3
(1, -1, '2019-01-01 01:05:01'), -- 3.1
(1, -1, '2019-01-01 01:06:01'), -- 3.2
(1, 1, '2019-01-01 01:01:01'), -- 1.2
(1, 1, '2019-01-01 01:08:01'), -- 4.2
(2, 1, '2019-01-01 01:08:01') -- 5.1
;
```

All I did is swapped the ValueCreated between the first and seventh rows, so now the `FirstID` of the first group is `7` and `LastID` is `1`. Your query returns correct result. My simple query above doesn't.

Here is the variant that produces correct result. I decided to use `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` functions to get the appropriate IDs. Again, run the query CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to see what is going on.
This variant produces the same result as your query even with the adjusted sample data set.

```
WITH
CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT
        [ValueId]
        ,[ListId]
        ,[ValueDelta]
        ,[ValueCreated]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ListID ORDER BY ValueCreated) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ListID, ValueDelta ORDER BY ValueCreated) AS rn2
    FROM [Value]
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        ValueId
        ,ListId
        ,ValueDelta
        ,ValueCreated
        ,rn1
        ,rn2
        ,rn1-rn2 AS Diff
        ,FIRST_VALUE(ValueID) OVER(
            PARTITION BY ListID, ValueDelta, rn1-rn2 ORDER BY ValueCreated
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS FirstID
        ,LAST_VALUE(ValueID) OVER(
            PARTITION BY ListID, ValueDelta, rn1-rn2 ORDER BY ValueCreated
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LastID
    FROM CTE_RN
)
SELECT
    ListID
    ,FirstID
    ,LastID
    ,MIN(ValueCreated) AS FirstCreated
    ,MAX(ValueCreated) AS LastCreated
    ,ValueDelta
    ,COUNT(*) AS ValueCount
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY
    ListID
    ,ValueDelta
    ,rn1-rn2
    ,FirstID
    ,LastID
ORDER BY FirstCreated;
```

Comment: *This is poetry.* And far faster than my brute version. And also figured it out. The row number difference that maintains over sets... nice! **Thank you.**

Comment: Come to think about it. `FirstId` and `LastId` are quite irrelevant. This just builds a stats view of streaks, periods and counts. If I need any clear data about the set, I can always query between the dates and pull the values. So even the first query works if I remove the Ids from it. So turned both queries into views, one with Ids and one without. Once I populate more data, I'll also be able to compare performance. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome @CodeAngry. You understand the main idea, so you can adjust it to your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE that adds a Row_Number column, partitioned by `GroupId` and `Value` and ordered by `Created`.

Then select from the CTE, GROUP BY `GroupId` and `Value`; use COUNT(*) to get the `Count`, and use correlated subqueries to select the `ValueId` with the MIN(RowNumber) (which will always be 1, so you can just use that instead of MIN) and the MAX(RowNumber) to get `FirstId` and `LastId`.

Although, now that I've noticed you're using SQL Server 2017, you should be able to use [First_Value() and Last_Value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of correlated subqueries.

Comment: I think your solution is pretty much what Vladimir wrote. But my SQL force was not strong enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After many iterations I think I have a working solution. I'm absolutely sure it's far from optimal but it works.

**Link is here**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ee9f/3

**Sample data:**

```
create table [Value]
(
    [ValueId] bigint not null identity(1,1),
    [ListId] bigint not null,
    [ValueDelta] int not null,
    [ValueCreated] datetime2 not null,
    constraint [PK_Value] primary key clustered ([ValueId])
);

insert into [Value]
([ListId], [ValueDelta], [ValueCreated])
values
(1, 1, '2019-01-01 01:01:01'), -- 1.1
(1, 0, '2019-01-01 01:02:01'), -- 2.1
(1, 0, '2019-01-01 01:03:01'), -- 2.2
(1, 0, '2019-01-01 01:04:01'), -- 2.3
(1, -1, '2019-01-01 01:05:01'), -- 3.1
(1, -1, '2019-01-01 01:06:01'), -- 3.2
(1, 1, '2019-01-01 01:01:02'), -- 1.2
(1, 1, '2019-01-01 01:08:01'), -- 4.2
(2, 1, '2019-01-01 01:08:01') -- 5.1
```

**The Query that seems to work:**

```
-- this is the actual order of data
select *
from [Value]
order by [ListId] asc, [ValueCreated] asc;

-- there are 4 sets here
-- set 1 GroupId=1, Id=1&7, Value=1
-- set 2 GroupId=1, Id=2-4, Value=0
-- set 3 GroupId=1, Id=5-6, Value=-1
-- set 4 GroupId=1, Id=8-8, Value=1
-- set 5 GroupId=2, Id=9-9, Value=1

with [cte1] as
(
    select [v1].[ListId]
        ,[v2].[ValueId] as [FirstId], [v2].[ValueCreated] as [FirstCreated]
        ,[v1].[ValueId] as [LastId], [v1].[ValueCreated] as [LastCreated]
        ,isnull([v1].[ValueDelta], 0) as [ValueDelta]
    from [dbo].[Value] [v1]
        join [dbo].[Value] [v2] on [v2].[ListId] = [v1].[ListId]
            and isnull([v2].[ValueDeltaPrev], 0) = isnull([v1].[ValueDeltaPrev], 0)
            and [v2].[ValueCreated] <= [v1].[ValueCreated] and not exists (
                select 1
                from [dbo].[Value] [v3]
                where 1=1
                    and ([v3].[ListId] = [v1].[ListId])
                    and ([v3].[ValueCreated] between [v2].[ValueCreated] and [v1].[ValueCreated])
                    and [v3].[ValueDelta] != [v1].[ValueDelta]
            )
), [cte2] as
(
    select [t1].*
    from [cte1] [t1]
    where not exists (select 1 from [cte1] [t2] where [t2].[ListId] = [t1].[ListId]
        and ([t1].[FirstId] != [t2].[FirstId] or [t1].[LastId] != [t2].[LastId])
        and [t1].[FirstCreated] between [t2].[FirstCreated] and [t2].[LastCreated]
        and [t1].[LastCreated] between [t2].[FirstCreated] and [t2].[LastCreated]
        )
)
select [ListId], [FirstId], [LastId], [FirstCreated], [LastCreated], [ValueDelta] as [ValueDelta]
    ,(select count(*) from [dbo].[Value] where [ListId] = [t].[ListId] and [ValueCreated] between [t].[FirstCreated] and [t].[LastCreated]) as [ValueCount]
from [cte2] [t];
```

How it works:

- join table to self on same list but only on older (or equal date to handle single sets) values
- join again on self and exclude any overlaps keeping only largest date set
- once we identify largest sets, we then count entries in set dates

*If anyone can find a better / friendlier solution, you get the answer.*

**PS**: *The dumb straightforward Cursor approach seems a lot faster than this. Still testing.*